# Jira Service Desk API call returning 401 from c# web application

Tags: c#, jira-rest-api

This literally worked this morning and now it returns a 401 error (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized).

In addition, I can no longer use Postman to test, same thing  Unauthorized (401).

However, if I log into Jira and then open a new tab I can paste in the api call and poof, instant json response. So it appears that the credentials are correct.

```
        var uriString = "https://journal.atlassian.net/rest/servicedeskapi/request?start=" + start.ToString() + "&limit=" + limit.ToString();
        var uri = new Uri(uriString);

        //var username = "my.email@someplace.com";
        //var password = "mypassword";

        var username = util.GetJiraAPIusername();
        var password = util.GetJiraAPIpassword();

        ViewBag.URI = uri;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;  // Blocking call!
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: It turned out to be due to an change on Atlassian's side. Once the Jira administrator had made the necessary changes to my account I was able to log in and use Postman again.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloudkb/jira-service-desk-cloud-rest-api-changes-to-atlassian-account-940700797.html

> On 1 January, 2018, we're changing how you authenticate users with the Jira Service Desk Cloud REST API.
>
> Right now, the REST API supports authentication for all users. However, on 1 January, users will need to have an Atlassian Account to authenticate against the REST API.
>
> If users on your instance are authenticating against the REST API but do not have Atlassian Accounts, you'll need to convert them to Atlassian Account. Here's how:
>
> 1. Go to Site administration > User management > Jira Service Desk >
>      Portal only customers.
> 2. Select the user you want to convert, then click Convert to Atlassian Account.
> 3. Go to id.atlassian.com and log in with the user's email address.
> 4. Go to Security > API tokens.
> 5. Click Create API token.
> 6. Copy the token and use it as you would a password for basic authentication. The username is the user's email address.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your request headers? I'm using Fiddler Web Debugger (you can use whatever tool you want that does this) to intercept and log all HTTP requests. You should see something like this on the request headers your're making:

[image]